# Creating interactive book mobile application

Tags: android, animation, andengine

I am creating an interactive book application for Android. Currently I am using AndEngine.

The interactive book has 30 scenes with different animations and backgrounds. That means will use at least 30 different backgrounds. Also there are some heavy animations that takes a large part of the screen.

For example, there is one scene which shows a little kid crying, that little kid image takes most portion of the screen. Also there is a scene, there is a large gift box, and then it opens and shows some toys. (The animation is almost full screen, much more like a video)

I am a little bit confused about how can I optimize the application. The goal is to reduce load and lag.

There are several questions :
1.) The common best practices is to use sprite-sheets. Should I put all the different backgrounds and sprites in one file?
2.) Should I load all the backgrounds and sprites first then use it throughout the application? Or should I load only the required background and sprite at the beginning on every scene? (When starting scene 1, loads background and sprites for scene 1 only)
3.) For the heavy animations (like a video), what is the best practices for creating them?